# Calling template function without <>; type inference

Tags: c++, templates, types, inference

If I have a function template with `typename T`, where the compiler can set the type by itself, I do not have to write the type explicitly when I call the function like:

```
template < typename T > 
T min( T v1, T v2 ) {
   return ( v1 < v2 ) ? v1: v2;
}
int i1 = 1, i2 = 2; int i3 = min( i1, i2 ); //no explicit <type>
```

But if I have a function template with two different typenames like:

```
template < typename TOut, typename TIn >
TOut round( TIn v ) {
   return (TOut)( v + 0.5 );
}
double d = 1.54;
int i = round<int>(d); //explicit <int>
```

Is it true that I always have to specify at least 1 typename? I assume the reason is because C++ can not distinguish functions between different return types.

But if I use a void function and handover a reference, again I must not explicitly specify the return typename:

```
template < typename TOut, typename TIn > 
void round( TOut & vret, TIn vin ) {
   vret = (TOut)(vin + 0.5);
}
   double d = 1.54;
   int i; round(i, d); //no explicit <int>
```

Should the conclusion be to avoid functions with return and more prefer `void` functions that return via a reference when writing templates? Or is there a possibility to avoid explicitly writing the return type? Something like "type inference" for templates. Is "type inference" possible in C++0x?

Comment: Casting between types makes the type inference idea unwieldy, so you cannot overload on return types and must specify it when it's a template parameter.

Comment: You might want to work on your rounding algorithm. What should -1.54 come out as? And: what if you want to get a rounded **double** value?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Overload resolution is done only based on function arguments; the return value is not used at all. If the return type cannot be determined based on the arguments, you will have to specify it explicitly.

I would not go down the path of "returning" a value through a reference parameter; that makes the calling code unclear. For example, I'd prefer this:

```
double x = round<double>(y);
```

over this:

```
double x;
round(x, y);
```

because in the latter case, it's easy to confuse input and output, and it's not at all clear that `x` is being modified.

In the particular case of `round`, you probably need only one or two types for `TOut` anyway, so you could just leave that template argument out:

```
template<typename TIn>
int roundToInt(TIn v) {
    return (int)(v + 0.5);
}
```

I find `roundToInt(x)` a little clearer than `round<int>(x)` because it's clear what the `int` type is used for.

Comment: Concerning clarity: `round_to<int>(x)`? ;)

Comment: @UncleBens, I'd say `roundToInt(x)` is more clear than `roundTo<int>(x)` which is *much more clear* than `round<int>(x)`.

Comment: That being said, `roundTo<int>(x)` certainly is a good alternative if you want to maintain the benefit of writing the templated function once, rather than writing a separate function for each output type to round to, while still getting the ability to round to a multitude of types. But, under most situations where you're only rounding to a few types anyway, I think the explicitness of `roundToInt(x)` is better than letting someone round to anything, so I'd choose `roundToInt(x)` (plus define one or two more following this pattern) unless I need to let someone round to virtually *any* type.

Answer (score 3):

> the conclusion be to avoid functions with return and more prefer void functions that return via a reference when writing templates

No, why? What do you gain? Only type inference (so less code to write). But you *lose* the much more logical syntax of assigning a value (and consequently more code to write). So one thing gained, another lost. I don’t see the benefit in general.

It may even *help* to have to specify the template type explicitly: consider the case of `lexical_cast`. Not specifying the return template type would be confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Let me add to what the others have said by saying you should prefer C++ casting over C-style casting.

```
vret = (TOut)(vin + 0.5);
```

versus

```
vret = static_cast<TOut>(vin + 0.5);
```

static cast will always fail if you try to convert unrelated types.  This can help with debugging.

Comment: And you'll have compile time warnings/errors too, much better than finding out at runtime.

Comment: What would the types involved have to be, so that a `static_cast` would yield a different result than a C-style cast in this template? (Yes, in a utility function you might strive for good style, but I don't see that much benefit in pure mathematical code doing conversion between number types - to warrant a post, and not perhaps a comment.)

Comment: You may be over this post, but I had to chime in. If you use a `static_cast`, an error means that the object/executable can't even exist; then the converse is true, that is, if you have an object/executable, you know that the `static_cast` was valid between types. As you move further into template metaprogramming, you will need more control over types within their inheritance trees, e.g. in CRTP.