# template function roundTo int, float -> truncation

Tags: c++, templates, function, return

according to this question:
[Calling template function without <>; type inference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833730/calling-template-function-without-type-inference)
the round function I will use in the future now looks like:

```
template < typename TOut, typename TIn >
TOut roundTo( TIn value ) {
   return static_cast<TOut>( value + 0.5 );
}
   double d = 1.54;
   int i = rountTo<int>(d);
```

However it makes sense only if it will be used to round to integral datatypes like char, short, int, long, long long int, and it's unsigned counterparts.
If it ever will be used with a TOut As float or long double it will deliver s***.

```
double d = 1.54;
float f = roundTo<float>(d);
// aarrrgh now float is 2.04;
```

I was thinking of a specified overload of the function but ...
that's not possible...
How would you solve this problem?
many thanks in advance
Oops

Comment: What about negative numbers? For example for -1.54, your function would round up to -1, and not down to -2? (If you implemented the fix by Alex Martelli)

Comment: @Jacob you are right definitely, that's the next problem of the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the closest integer value, cast to `TOut`,

```
static_cast<TOut>( static_cast<long long>(value + 0.5) );
```

`floor` should also work as an alternative to the inner cast.  The point is not to rely on the cast to an unknown type to perform any truncation -- ensure the truncation explicitly, with a `floor` or a `cast` to a well-known integral type, *then* perform the further casting you need to return the specified type.

Comment: I'd really suggest using `floor()`, as using the cast to `long long` will cause undefined behaviour for big numbers.

Comment: @jpalecek, since the OP means to use `char`, `short`, and `int` as typical values of `TOut`, the intermediate cast to `long long` can't do any more damage than the final cast to, e.g., `short` will inevitably do afterwards.  `floor`'s fine too, of course, but an intermediate cast might be microscopically faster (needs measuring on your specific compiler and platform, of course).

Comment: I also mentioned TOut As long long int.

Comment: @Oops, sure, but my point is that, if TOut is any integral type shorter than or equal to long long, the nested static cast can't hurt (if your C++ compiler has integral types longer than that, you could use the longest of those in the nested static cast, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Try using floor:

```
template < typename TOut, typename TIn >
TOut roundTo( TIn value ) {
   return static_cast<TOut>(floor( value + 0.5 ));
}

double d = 1.54;
int i = rountTo<int>(d);
double d = 1.54;
float f = roundTo<float>(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could disable your function for non-integral return types:

```
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/utility.hpp>

template < typename TOut, typename TIn >
typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_integral<TOut>, TOut>::type roundTo( TIn value ) {
   return static_cast<TOut>( value + 0.5 );
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't a utility that correctly chooses `floor` or `ceil` be handy?