# Getting no match for operator overloaded

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, type-conversion

I overloaded the *= operator with this member function:

```
template<class U>
Matriz<T> & operator*=(const Matriz<U> & valor);
```

And also I have a constructor to matriz like this:

```
Matriz(const std::vector<T> & vector);
```

Well, I would like to make something like this:

```
double vetor[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
std::vector<double> vec(vetor, vetor + 3);
Matriz<double> A("src//imatriz.dat"); //Creates a matrix with parameters from a file.
A*=vec;
```

That is, I would like to multiply a matrix by a vector. The problem is that compiler returns that there is no match for the operator.

---EDIT2---

As suggested, I also tried this:

```
template<class U>
friend Matriz<T> & operator*=(Matriz<U> & lhs, const Matriz<U> & rhs)
```

but A*=vec still doesn't work.

Any idea? If you need more code there's no problem to put it here.

Comment: If your overload is a global function (can't understand from your paste), it will fail. You may consider making it a class method.

Comment: It is a class method.

Comment: then you should overload `*=` taking vector as a parameter?`A*=vec;` should embed a call to something like this `operator*=(A,vec);` where vec is of type vector<double>.

Comment: Instantiation of variable A seems weird. Try something like this: `Matriz<double> A = Matriz<double>(vec)`

Comment: @Leandro The answers so far are all correct, but your underlying question **why exactly the compiler didn't perform an implicit conversion** hasn't been addressed. The thread [C++ implicit type conversion with template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787593/c-implicit-type-conversion-with-template) answers it.

Comment: @djf I have tried this answer, like you can see in my new EDIT2, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Leandro My comment wasn't meant as a critique or anything. I just wanted to point out that the behavior you're getting is correct according the C++ standard

Comment: @djf Yeah, I can see that it isn't a critique, no problem! I want just to find out a way to solve this problem. That answer that you posted is pointing to a correct way but something else is wrong into my code...thanks for your comment, it was the best try until now.

Comment: @Leandro @billz and @Koushik both gave solutions which work. Let me reiterate the problem quickly. When you're working with templates, the compiler first tries to figure out the correct values of U and T (your template parameters). It doesn't even look at implicit conversions, default arguments, overloads etc. The reason it fails to compile is because there's simply no substitution for U to turn the expression `Matriz<T> & operator*=(const Matriz<U> & valor)` into `Matriz<double> & operator*=(const std::vector<double>& valor)`. It has to give up at this point. I hope this isn't too convoluted.

Comment: So @djf is there no way to do it without implement another operator only to take care of vectors?

Comment: @Leandro In _general_ no. There are some pretty advanced techniques.... Anyway, defining another overload for vectors seems to be your best option

Answer (score 2):

To make below statement work:

```
A *= vec;
```

You need another `operator*=` for vector type:

```
template<class U>
Matriz<U> & operator*=(const std::vector<U> & valor);
```

constructor will operate on new constructed object but will not convert existing object, for example, below statement should work:

```
A*=std::vector<double>(vetor, vetor + 3);
```

see [live sample](http://ideone.com/mtJY9L)

Comment: But if I pass a vector to the operator with matrix, why not it converts to matrix? See, there is a constructor that receives a vector.

Comment: +1 thats exactly what i also said. or may be he can take another template parameter which tells the type that should be multiplied with.

Comment: @Leandro you are multiplying and not constructing anything there. there is no default conversion as you expect.

Comment: This solution I have also tried. It's ok, works well, but I wanna know why I can't make it without this overloading of the operator.

Comment: Yeah, but, if I pass a int to get multiplied by a double it works fine...I would like to do something like this.

Comment: Yeah, exactly, but I put this in my code and it doesn't work.

Comment: Hey @billz I made some changes in your code and tried it. It seems that maybe the problem is with template...

Comment: quite possible, coz the implicit conversion from vector to Matriz is obvious as you have a constructor which takes vector as parameter.

Comment: You need to post more code, also post what's the error message. ;)

Comment: In the question comments, @djf gave me an idea about what I need, but it still doesn't wokr. So, See there the problem. If you still need more code I could try to give you some.

Answer (score 1):

you could maybe do this

```
template<typename T, typename conv =  std::vector<T> > //for the Matriz class
```

now operator is

```
Matriz<T>& operator *= (const conv& vec);
```

also the constructor as below

```
Matriz(const conv& vec);
```

EDIT 2:
you could do this otherwise

for the constructor use this

```
template<typename TYPE2MUL>
Matriz(const TYPE2MUL& var)
```

after this you can use

```
A *= vec;
```

because it will call op as so `operator *=(A,Matriz<vector>(vec));` no need for EDIT 1 or prior to that.

Comment: I have made a version without template and works even A*=vec...maybe the problem is with templates.

Comment: Any idea how to show compiler that it's ok...that it can use that method?

Comment: maybe take another template parameter for specifying the type to multiply

Comment: @Leandro check out EDIT2 you might find it useful.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that I'll have a constructor that receives everything. So one could try Matriz<t>(int a).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to define another operator '=', the following code is OK.

```
A *= Matriz<double>(vec).
```