# Why does g++ not warn/err while concatenating an integer to a string using +=

Tags: java, c++, g++, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>                     
using namespace std; 

int main()                  
{                                                                                    
       string name = "John ";                     
       int age = 32;         
       name += age;    
       cout << name << endl;
       return 0;                                          
}
```

The code compiles successfully but betrays at run time as it silently ignores the concatenation part and prints:

```
John
```

I know that we need to use *stringstream* for the task. But why does the above code compile?
Because the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;                                                                 

int main()                       
{                                                                                    
       string name = "John ";                              
       int age = 55;                                    
       name = name + age;             
       cout << name << endl;      
       return 0;
}
```

duly throws and error:

> error: no match for ‘operator+’ in ‘name + age’

I know from Java that `a += b` is different from `a = a + b` as the former construct typecasts the result to the type of a.  [Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2). But I don't think this would matter in C++ as we can always do:

```
   int a = 1;                                                                       
   float f = 3.33;                                                                  
   a = a + f;
```

without worrying about a possible loss of precision warning unlike Java. Need citation for this in C++.

So now if we assume that `name += age;` expands to `name = string (name + age);` then also the code should not have compiled simply because name + age is not legal.

Comment: Are you sure it ignores the concatenation? I get `John 7`, which is what I'd expect since 55 is the ASCII value for `'7'`.

Comment: Also, your assumption is wrong. For class types, `a += b` is not equivalent to `a = a+b`. The first uses `operator+=`, the second uses `operator+` and `operator=`, and it's entirely up to the class writer how these operators are implemented.

Comment: True. But I knew that += for strings works like a + b. And yes it prints John 7. I had age = 32 on my machine. Typo. All's clear now. Thanks!

Comment: Without loss of precision? If a is an int, how is that going to happen? Seems like the .33 wont make it *to* the first operator. What you wrote is ‘a.operator=(a.+(f.operator int()))‘

Comment: I meant warning. Updating it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: the 'The code compiles successfully but betrays at run time as it silently ignores the concatenation part and prints:' is still wrong, 32 is just ascii for a space. if you took the length of the string, you would see it grew by a character.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use the `-Wconversion` flag(*It is not clear to me why this is not included in -Wall*) also see the [Options to Request or Suppress Warnings](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) for more details. When I add that flag I see the following warning when using `gcc`:

```
 warning: conversion to 'char' from 'int' may alter its value [-Wconversion]
    name += age;  
         ^
```

and we can see that indeed [operator +=](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D) does support *char* and therefore the converted value is indeed being add to the end of `name`, it is not ignoring the operation at all. In *C++* [operator +](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B) for [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) is a different operator than *operator +=*.

In this specific case:

```
name += age;
```

would translate to something like this:

```
name.operator+=(static_cast<char>(age)) ;
```

and if we had a expression using *operator +* without an error like this one:

```
name = name + static_cast<char>( age );
```

would translate to:

```
operator+( name, static_cast<char>( age ) ) ;
```

The reason why this fails for *operator +* in your example is covered well in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9789036/1708801), basically *template functions* won't perform conversions and so require an exact match with the possible exception of *const/volatile qualifiers*.

**Update on Wconversion**

`gcc` has a [Wconversion Wiki](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/NewWconversion) with a *FAQ*, it is a bit dated but it does answer why this check is not included with the `-Wall` flag:

> Implicit conversions are very common in C. This tied with the fact that there is no data-flow in front-ends (see next question) results in hard to avoid warnings for perfectly working and valid code. Wconversion is designed for a niche of uses (security audits, porting 32 bit code to 64 bit, etc.) where the programmer is willing to accept and workaround invalid warnings. Therefore, it shouldn't be enabled if it is not explicitly requested.

Comment: And is a += b; expanded as a = (type of a) a + b; in C++ as it is done in Java?

Comment: @KodingKid assuming `a` is a *std::string* this will translate to `a.operator+=(b)` with a suitable type conversion for `b` if needed.

Comment: @KodingKid No.  When dealing with overloaded operators, `+=` and `+` are entirely unrelated, as far as the language is concerned.  (Of course, any good programmer will always provide both if he provides one, with the expected semantic relationship.)

Comment: @KodingKid Also, I don't think Java defines it this way either.  If I write `someComplicatedExpressionWithSideEffects += 'x'`, `someComplicatedExpressionWithSideEffects` will not be evaluated twice.

Comment: From Java docs, [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2] 
"A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent to E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that E1 is evaluated only once."

Comment: @KodingKid just keep in mind that *Java* and *C++* are very different in many ways and trying to understand *C++* through *Java* is probably not a good idea.