# tuple/pair template deduction fails with list initialization

Tags: c++, templates

In the following code:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3ed46591fe7d3af

```
struct Thingy
{  
  template<class T1>
  void operator=(std::pair<int, T1> p){

  }  
};    

int main()
{
  Thingy thing;
  thing={1, "asd"};
  /*
       This works fine:
       std::pair<int, int> p(1, "asd");
       thing=p;
  */
    return 0;
}
```

I have this error:

`couldn't deduce template parameter 'T1'`

It seems that list initialization (curly braces) prevents type deduction. But why?

Comment: `{1, "asd"}` is not a `pair`, and to deduce to a pair, compile would have to check each type to see it would be a valid pair (as `std::pair<int, std::string>`and `std::pair<int, const char*>` and `std::pair<int, char(&)[4]>`)...

Comment: *"This works fine: std::pair<int, int> p(1, "asd");"* I don't think so. `"asd"` to `int`...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is templated overload resolution and implicit conversions ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787593/c-implicit-type-conversion-with-template))

I can't quite match the exact usage, but the following works:

```
template<typename T1>
struct Thingy
{  
  void operator=(const std::pair<int, T1>& p) {
    std::cout << "operator=" << std::endl;
  }  

  void set(std::pair<int, T1> p){
    std::cout << "set" << std::endl;    
  }  
};    

int main()
{
  Thingy<std::string> thing;
  thing = {1, "asd"};
  thing.set({1, "asd"});    // same here
  /*
       This works fine:
       std::pair<int, int> p(1, "asd");
       thing=p;
  */
    return 0;
}
```

[live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e0ba483babbee455)