# Implicit conversion between templates

Tags: c++, templates, implicit-conversion, conversion-operator

I don't quite understand why this code here does not compile.
It should be possible to call dist() like so:

```
dist(GenericVec2<T>,GenericVec3<T>)
```

(However horrible this may be). The idea is that the GenericVec3 argument gets implicitly converted into a GenericVec2 by the conversion operator.
I found this question here

[C++ implicit type conversion with template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787593/c-implicit-type-conversion-with-template)

, but I'm not so sure if it can be applied to my problem (setting the conversion operator to "`friend`" didn't work). VS outputs the following error:

```
error C2672: 'dist': no matching overloaded function found
error C2784: 'F dist(const GenericVec2<F> &,const GenericVec2<F> &)': could not deduce template argument for 'const GenericVec2<F> &' from 'Vec3'
note: see declaration of 'dist'
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename F> struct GenericVec2
{
    GenericVec2<F>::GenericVec2(F _x = 0, F _y = 0) : x(_x), y(_y) {}

    F x;
    F y;
};
using Vec2 = GenericVec2<float>;

template<typename F> struct GenericVec3
{
    GenericVec3<F>::GenericVec3(F _x = 0, F _y = 0, F _z = 0) : x(_x), y(_y), z(_z) {}

    operator GenericVec2<F>()               { return *reinterpret_cast<GenericVec2<F>*>(&x); }
    operator const GenericVec2<F>() const   { return *reinterpret_cast<const GenericVec2<F>*>(&x); }

    F x;
    F y;
    F z;
};
using Vec3 = GenericVec3<float>;

template<typename F> F dist(const GenericVec2<F>& a, const GenericVec2<F>& b)
{
    return std::hypot(a.x - b.x, a.y - b.y);
}

int main()
{
    Vec2 a{ 2.0f, 3.0f };
    Vec3 b{ 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    Vec2 c = b;

    float d = dist(a, Vec2{ b });   // works
    float e = dist(a, b);           // doesn't compile

    std::cin.ignore();

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

-Thomas

Comment: Your `reinterpret_cast` breaks strict aliasing and reading from a `union` member other than the one last assigned to is also UB. Throw that code away and start from scratch, it is broken beyond repair. If you don't see why I'm saying this, it's time to read a good book.

Comment: I can't, it's not my code and not easily exchanged. I just need to know how to get it to compile (ideally without doing the explicit `dist(a, Vec2{b})` conversion.

Comment: I have removed the union, as it wasn't part of the actual problem (and indeed not very pretty). Originial question still stands.

Comment: In case that was not clear in my first comment: This code is plain incorrect and illegal. Making it compile will not make it better *at all*. This code can not be used, neither in production, POC nor toy programs. (Still applies after the `union` was removed, see strict aliasing.)

Comment: You can't combine user-defined implicit conversions with template argument deduction.  `dist<float>(a, b)` should also work.

Comment: Understood, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that, in

```
template<typename F> F dist(const GenericVec2<F>& a, const GenericVec2<F>& b)
```

you cannot deduced second parameter from `GenericVec2<float>`.
One solution is to make the function non template thanks to `friend`:

```
template<typename F> struct GenericVec2
{
    GenericVec2<F>::GenericVec2(F _x = 0, F _y = 0) : x(_x), y(_y) {}


    friend F dist(const GenericVec2& a, const GenericVec2& b)
    {
        return std::hypot(a.x - b.x, a.y - b.y);
    }

    F x;
    F y;
};
```

Comment: That worked! Gonna have to take a look at the `friend` keyword, I guess...

Answer (score 0):

To implicit conversion be possible the target class shall have a constructor that receives the source type (or a type convertible from a source type) as a parameter. The casting operator as defined in `GenericVec3` is used in explicit casting operations.

So you should define the following constructor in your `GenericVec2` class

`GenericVec2(const GenericVec3<F>& v3) { ... }`

Comment: No change whatsoever here. Same error as before. Current code: https://pastebin.com/yzTECFHn