# Implicit instantiation of function argument

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to figure out how implicit instantiation of function arguments works. For some reason in the first example, the `bar()` call interprets the `{12,41}` as an initializer list. If I change the `foo` signature to `auto foo(std::pair<int,int> bar)` the `{12,41}` is implicitly converted to an `std::pair<int,int>`.

For example

```
template<typename T, typename U>
auto foo(std::pair<T,U> arg) { return arg; }
auto bar()                   { return foo({12,41}); }
```

fails with error:

```
<source>: In function 'auto bar()':
104 : <source>:104:50: error: no matching function for call to 'foo(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
 auto bar()                   { return foo({12,41}); }
                                                  ^
103 : <source>:103:6: note: candidate: 'template<class T, class U> auto foo(std::pair<_T1, _T2>)'
 auto foo(std::pair<T,U> arg) { return arg; }
      ^~~
103 : <source>:103:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
104 : <source>:104:50: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'T'
 auto bar()                   { return foo({12,41}); }
                                                  ^
```

but

```
auto foo(std::pair<int,int> arg) { return arg; }
auto bar()                       { return foo({12,41}); }
```

works. Would someone care to elaborate why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the usual reason: implicit conversions tend to not happen in the same way (or at all) with templated functions. In your second example:

```
auto foo(std::pair<int,int> arg) { return arg; }
auto works()                     { return foo({12,41}); }
```

`foo` is a function, not a function template. `std::pair` has a non-explicit, two argument constructor: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair. A brace pack with n entries can be implicitly converted to a type that has an n-ary implicit constructor. So you get implicit conversion from `{12,31}` to `std::pair<int, int>`.

When a function template is called, template deduction will try to deduce the templates so that the arguments match. In this process, the full range of implicit conversions is not available. Only a very special few conversions are allowed: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction. Basically, CV conversions, derived-to-base conversions, and some pointer qualification and function pointer conversions.

So:

```
template <class T, class U>
auto foo(std::pair<T, U> arg) { return arg; }
auto bar()                    { return foo({12,41}); }
```

Fails, because when `foo` is called, it tries to substitute template parameters into `foo` to make the call arguments and the parameters match up, but they cannot be made to match up precisely enough.

I am not commenting on the `pair<auto, auto>` syntax, but the situation is exactly the same with the more explicit syntax so I don't think that's really the heart of the issue.

This has been discussed before on SO here: [C++ implicit type conversion with template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787593/c-implicit-type-conversion-with-template), so it's worth reading for more information. Although, note that the accepted answer there incorrectly says that only CV qualification changes are allowed when matching a function template; that isn't quite true (maybe I'll propose an edit there).