# Why does the implicit type conversion not work in template deduction?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

In the following code, I want to call a template function by implicitly converting an `int` to a `Scalar<int>` object.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename Dtype>
class Scalar{
public:
  Scalar(Dtype v) : value_(v){}
private:
  Dtype value_;
};

template<typename Dtype>
void func(int a, Scalar<Dtype> b){ 
  cout << "ok" <<endl;
}

int main(){
  int a = 1;
  func(a, 2); 
  //int b = 2;
  //func(a, b);
  return 0;
}
```

Why does the template argument deduction/substitution fail? And the commented-codes are also wrong.

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:19:12: error: no matching function for call to ‘func(int&, int)’
   func(a, 2);
            ^
test.cpp:19:12: note: candidate is:
test.cpp:13:6: note: template<class Dtype> void func(int, Scalar<Dtype>)
 void func(int a, Scalar<Dtype> b){
      ^
test.cpp:13:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:19:12: note:   mismatched types ‘Scalar<Dtype>’ and ‘int’
   func(a, 2);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ implicit type conversion with template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787593/c-implicit-type-conversion-with-template)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) is not that smart: it does not (by design) consider user-defined conversions. And `int` ->  `Scalar<int>` is a user-defined conversion.

If you want to use TAD, you need to convert your argument at the caller site:

```
func(a, Scalar<int>{2});
```

or define a deduction guide<sup>1</sup> for `Scalar` and call `f`:

```
func(a, Scalar{2}); // C++17 only
```

Alternatively, you can explicitly instantiate `f`:

```
func<int>(a, 2);
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> The default deduction guide is sufficient: [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e58335567bb7d6a7).

Comment: I've tested all three of your solutions and they will work as is; however if the OP declared `Scalar()` as `explicit` the third one will not compile. Not sure if this is something worth mentioning or not, but might be something important for the OP to be aware of.

Answer (score 4):

```
template<typename Dtype>
void func(int a, Scalar<Dtype> b){ 
  cout << "ok" <<endl;
}
template<typename Dtype>
void func(int a, Dtype b){ 
  func(a, Scalar<Dtype>(std::move(b)));
}
```

template argument deduction is pattern matching, and it only matches the types or their base types exactly.  It does no conversion.

Conversion is done later, at overload resolution & function call time.

Here, we add another overload that explicitly forwards to the one you want.

Comment: You probably want `b` to be a `Dtype&&` and use `std::forward` instead of `std::move` for perfect forwarding.