# Template deduction failed

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-argument-deduction

I've been trying to implement some generic wrappers (similar to std::span). However, I can't seem to get the template deduction/ conversion working. I'm not sure why. Below is a minimum "not-compiling" example

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Wrapper
{
public:
    using ElementType       = T;
    using ValueType         = std::remove_cv<T>;
    using Pointer           = ElementType*;

    constexpr Wrapper(const Wrapper& lhs):
        mPtr(lhs.mPtr)
    {}

    template<typename U, std::size_t N>
    Wrapper(const std::array<U,N>& lhs):
        mPtr(lhs.data())
    {}

    template<typename U, std::size_t N>
    Wrapper(std::array<U,N>& lhs):
        mPtr(lhs.data())
    {}

    Pointer mPtr;
};

// Deduction guidelines
template <typename Type, std::size_t Size>
Wrapper(std::array<Type, Size>&)->Wrapper<Type>;

template <typename Type, std::size_t Size>
Wrapper(const std::array<Type, Size>&)->Wrapper<const Type>;

/// The function that is supposed convert array to the Wrapper
template<typename T>
void TestFunction(const Wrapper<T>& data)
{
    // do something with the data
    std::cout << data.mPtr;
}

// Try and use Test Function passing in an array
void LetsTest(std::array<float, 128>& data)
{
     TestFunction(data);
}
```

Could someone please explain what I am missing or not understanding?

The compiler complaint is

> #1 with ARM gcc 10.2.1 (none) : In function 'void LetsTest(std::array<float, 128>&)': :47:22: error: no matching
> function for call to 'TestFunction(std::array<float, 128>&)'    47 |
> TestFunction(data);
> |                      ^ :38:6: note: candidate: 'template<class T, class U> void TestFunction(const Wrapper&)'
> 38 | void TestFunction(const Wrapper& data)
> |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~ :38:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed: :47:22: note:
> 'std::array<float, 128>' is not derived from 'const Wrapper'
> 47 |     TestFunction(data);
> |                      ^

Comment: The deduction doesn't work for inner types of a template type. Hence, `T` cannot be deduced in `TestFunction(const Wrapper<T>&)`. I could swear I have already seen duplicates but I failed to find a nice one. Please, have a look yourself: [google "c++ template deduction containers site:stackoverflow.com"](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+template+deduction+containers+site:stackoverflow.com). I believe you will also find solutions to come around (e.g. a template template argument or SFINAE).

Comment: `TestFunction` has a `U` template parameter but that's not being deduced or provided.

Comment: @0x499602D2 For the record: Removing the `U` parameter doesn't change it: [Tried on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b79a5b5d475e78a4) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff Because he has another issue. You can't implicitly convert an `std::array` to a `Wrapper` because the constructor is a template.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Changing constructor to non-template (`Wrapper(std::vector<T> const& lhs)` does not change anything (at least with GCC), so the constructor being template does not seem to be the reason behind.

Comment: @Aconcagua Simply changing the function call in `LetsTest` to `TestFunction(Wrapper<float>(data))` solved the issue for me.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Sure it does. It constructs the Wrapper object explicitly – and then we can deduce the template argument from the specialised type easily. Or we could just provide the template parameter explicitly: `testFunction<float>(data);` But that's not in the sense of the question which tried to deduce the correct constructor already.

Comment: Looks very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/53227713/103167

Comment: Template argument deduction [doesn't consider implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Implicit_conversions). For that reason, it cannot deduce `T` from an argument that's not a `Wrapper<something>`

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I'll guess I'll just have to code some of the overloads manually.