# Overload resolution and template argument deduction - why is 0 special?

Tags: c++, templates, overload-resolution, template-argument-deduction, function-templates

In the following example, `0` behaves in a special way: it chooses a different overload than one would expect for one example function call. I would like to know why. My understanding is also below.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void f(T a) {
    std::cout << "first" << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void f(T* a) {
    std::cout << "second" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    f(0);
    f<size_t>(0);
    f<size_t>(0UL);
    
    f(1);
    f<size_t>(1);
}
```

Output:

```
first
second
first
first
first
```

My understanding:

`f(0)` - template argument deduction, integer literal `0` is `int` type, hence first `f` is chosen with `T=int`

`f<size_t>(0)` - explicit template instantiation with **integer promotion**, chosen type is `T=size_t`, first function is chosen and `0` is **promoted** from `int` to `size_t` (**I AM WRONG HERE**)

`f<size_t>(0UL)` - same as above but with **no promotion** (0 is already type `size_t`)

`f(1)` - same as 1.

`f<size_t>(1)` - same as 2. (I am right here for some reason??)

**NOTE:**

I know that `0` is implicitly convertible to a null pointer:

> A null pointer constant is an integer literal (5.13.2) with value zero or a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t

However, I also know from the standard that promotion has higher priority than conversion:

> Each type of standard conversion sequence is assigned one of three
> ranks:
>
> 1. Exact match: no conversion required, lvalue-to-rvalue
>    conversion, qualification conversion, function pointer
>    conversion,(since C++17) user-defined conversion of class type to the
>    same class
> 2. Promotion: integral promotion, floating-point promotion
> 3. Conversion: integral conversion, floating-point conversion,
>    floating-integral conversion, pointer conversion, pointer-to-member
>    conversion, boolean conversion, user-defined conversion of a derived
>    class to its base

Comment: Note that your first quote doesn't say there is a conversion. It says that integer literal with value zero *is* null pointer constant.

Comment: Alright, but i explicitly instantiated the first function with `T=size_t`, right? I didn't put `f<size_t*>`. Shouldn't compiler pick first template function `f` anyway?

Comment: @toxic With explicit template argument you have `void f(std::size_t)` and `void f(std::size_t*)` as valid overloads. The latter is chosen by overload resolution.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen No, then the call should be ambigious See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/djExd84sr). That is, when we have `void f(std::size_t*)` and `void f(std::size_t)` then the call `f(0)` would be ambigious.

Comment: @toxic Note that the term **explicit template instantiation** means something else than what you're using it for. So your statement *"explicit template instantiation with integer promotion..."* isn't technically correct.

Comment: You are right, this is not explicit template instantiation, and I agree with you on call ambiguity so I still don't understand what's exactly happening in the example above. By the way, you can write something like `int *a = 0UL;` where it gets converted to null ptr constant, but the chosen function `f(0UL)` is different than `f(0)`.

Comment: @user12002570 Hmm, templates have more rules to [break ties in overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Function_template_overloading). Despite the fact that they are [treated as these overloads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Additional_rules_for_function_template_candidates), compiler doesn't forget that they are templates and can still choose `T*` as better than `T`. But I don't want to get into explaining it, I don't feel confident enough about the topic.

Comment: `f<size_t>(0)` calls/uses the second template because of partial ordering. In short, the second overload is **more specialized** than the first. A nice example is given in this post on [partial ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17008568/12002570)

Comment: *"behaves in a special way"* -- What is special about it? It would be helpful to explain this (in words) before the code so that readers have some clue as to what to focus on. (See also [ask]: *"Introduce the problem before you post any code"*.)

Comment: Combining templates with overloading is tricky business and full of surprises. I still have nightmares about [this](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/049.htm) ancient Guru of the Week entry.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> `f<size_t>(0)` - explicit template instantiation with integer promotion, chosen type is `T=size_t`, first function is chosen and 0 is promoted from int to `size_t`

The reason `f<size_t>(0)` calls/uses the second overload `f(T*)` is because of [partial ordering rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17005985/what-is-the-partial-ordering-procedure-in-template-deduction). In particular, the second overload `f(T* a)` is **more specialized** than the first overload `f(T a)`.

Note that **if** we were to have ordinary(non-template) functions say `void f(std::size_t*)` and `void f(std::size_t)` then the call `f(0)` would've been ambiguous but with function templates(as in your case) the call `f(0)` prefers/selects the `void f(T*)` version because it is more specialized than `void f(T)`

---

> why `f(0)` calls first overload. I know that 0 is **implicitly convertible** to a null pointer:

Because [implicit conversions are not considered during template argument deduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53227713/why-does-the-implicit-type-conversion-not-work-in-template-deduction). This means that for the call `f(0)` only the first overload `void f(T a)` is **viable**. In other words, **the second overload `void f(T* a)` is not even viable for the call `f(0)`** .You can verify this in this [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Gd1oPzE8Y):

```
template<typename T>
void f(T* a) {
    std::cout << "second" << std::endl;
}
int main()
{
    f(0);//FAILS because implicit conversion are not considered during deduction   
}
```

Comment: @toxic Ok I am adding that as well. But in short, `f(0)` calls the first overload because **implicit conversions are not considered during deduction!!** This means that for the call `f(0)` only the first overload is viable!! You can verfiy this [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Gd1oPzE8Y)

Comment: @toxic I've added the explanation for why `f(0)` calls the first overload in my answer. Check out the updated answer and the demo/example there.

Comment: Thanks. Is it a bug that MSVC prefers `f(T*)` for `f<size_t>(0UL)` unlike other compilers? https://godbolt.org/z/TKecqfdfT

Comment: Yeah @Fedor that is a nice question, can somebody explain this? I really don't think this could be a bug.. could it?

Comment: I guess this is because `0UL` does not have `size_t` type in MSVC, and one has to use `0ULL` instead. Or better `f<size_t>(size_t(0))`, which will work in all compilers.

Comment: @toxic Yeah definitely a bug. See [submitted bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSVC-rejects-valid-program-involving-con/10571926).