# Template specialization - compiler cannot divine functional argument type

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to specialize a templated function with a functional argument, but the compiler is unable to infer the proper specialization. I get compiler errors unless I am explicit about the function type.

```
#include <functional>

int data;
using MyFunction = std::function<int()>;

template<class T> void set(const T& value)
{
    data = value;
}

template<> void set<MyFunction>(const MyFunction& f)
{
    data = f();
}

int main()
{
    set(1); // OK
    
    MyFunction f2 = []() { return 1; }; // OK
    set(f2);
    
    auto f1 = []() { return 1; }; // COMPILE ERROR
    set(f1);
    
    set([]() { return 1; }); // COMPILE ERROR

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler error (g++/c++11):

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void set(const T&) [with T = main()::<lambda()>]’:
main.cpp:26:8:   required from here
main.cpp:10:10: error: invalid user-defined conversion from ‘const main()::’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
   10 |     data = value;
      |     ~~~~~^~~~~~~
main.cpp:25:15: note: candidate is: ‘constexpr main()::::operator int (*)()() const’ (near match)
   25 |     auto f1 = []() { return 1; }; // COMPILE ERROR
```

Example code includes a boiled-down version of my attempts. Tried C++11, 14, 17, 20 with same results. MSVC 16 and g++, similar results.

I'm hoping/expecting the compiler to correctly infer the lambda function type and pick the correct specialization.

Comment: It has correctly inferred the lambdas' types -they are not `std::function<int()>` but unique, unnamed types. Implicit conversions are not considered in template instantiation and selection.

Comment: The problem is that `data` is `int` while `value` is a lambda(class type) and so `data=value` can't work. [Why does the implicit type conversion not work in template deduction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53227713/why-does-the-implicit-type-conversion-not-work-in-template-deduction)

Comment: A few thing, global variables are a bad idea. So I will put the data in a struct (wrapper_t). And then I would add set operations on that struct that can either accept an type_t or any kind of function like object that returns a type_t. Like this : https://onlinegdb.com/oZBqtCGI3

Comment: @user12002570 consider reopening. I think this is a different situation, where OP kind of doesn't know where to start. And I think implicit type conversion is not the main reason why this doesn't work.

Comment: @PepijnKramer The main problem is indeed that implicit conversions are not considered during deduction. For example, see [this demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MsYca8nT1) where I've removed the template and the program starts compiling. No need to reopen this.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen There was no need to reopen this. The problem is that implicit conversions are not considered during deduction.

Comment: @user12002570 And knowing that doesn't solve the problem for OP. The problem is the use of `std::function` when they really want any callable to be passed in.

Comment: `template <class T> void set(T const& value) { if constexpr (std::is_invocable_r_v<int, T>) { data = value(); } else { data = value; } }`

Comment: @user12002570 I am not missing that, I am just saying that the fact that there are other dupe targets is no reason to not reopen a question when the current dupe target is not the good one. One can look for a good target before closing the question

Comment: @user12002570 others disagree and vote to reopen, thats how it goes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm hoping/expecting the compiler to correctly infer the lambda function type and pick the correct specialization.

The **problem** is that implicit conversions are not considered during template argument deduction.

To solve this either **just provide ordinary non-template overload** instead of specialization or an alternative is to use [`std::is_invocable_r`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable) along with `constexpr if` as shown below:

##### Method 1

Here we use a non-template overload and `requires`(in C++20). Note that it is trivial to change(if needed) `requires` to SFINAE and is left as an exercise.

```
template<class T> void set(const T& value) requires(!std::is_invocable_v<T>)
{
    data = value;
}
//non template overload
void set(const MyFunction& f)
{
    data = f();
}
```

---

##### Method 2

Here we use `constexpr if` along with `std::is_invocable_v`.

```
template <class T> void set(T const& value) 
{ 
    if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<T>) 
    { 
        data = value(); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        data = value; 
    } 
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nYKGKax8s)

Comment: Why `std::is_invocable_r_v` when you can use `std::is_invocable_v`?

Comment: @NathanOliver Ah, forgot to remove the first template parameter. Updated.

Comment: Or are you using `std::is_invocable_r_v` to enforce the function returns an `int` so no implicit conversions happen?

Comment: Thank you. I attempted specialization because the non-template overload did not work in the first place (which I neglected to mention) https://onlinegdb.com/418HbwMV4

Comment: @GlennWaldron Yeah, `constexpr if` and `std::is_invocable_v` etc should solve that.

Comment: @GlennWaldron You can make the non-template version work. See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/j5azW68d1) where the non-template case works. Check out the updated answer where I've shown two ways to solve this.

Comment: @user12002570 Appreciate your insights and I've marked this as the answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

When I look at your code I do not see a reason to use templates at all:

```cpp
#include <functional>

int data;

using MyFunction = std::function<int()>;

void set(int value)
{
    data = value;
}

void set(const MyFunction& f)
{
    data = f();
}

int main()
{
    set(1);

    MyFunction f2 = []() { return 1; };
    set(f2);

    auto f1 = []() { return 1; };
    set(f1);

    set([]() { return 1; });

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/PM1z4sWcq

What is your rationale to use template here? Body of `set` when value is accepted makes seance only for `int` or something what is convertible to `int` (and conversion can be done implicitly by compiler when `set` is invoked). Without explanation why you think you need template I would recommend do not use template of function. Note that `std::function` resolves most of your problems. So it looks like your code is simple example of over-engineering.

Comment: I totally agree that a non-template solution is better here (at least until the OP will specify a good reason to do otherwise).

Comment: The code was a minimal example for the purposes of reproducing the issue.

Comment: @GlennWaldron I've wrote: `Without explanation why you think you need template I would recommend do not use template of function.` Provide more details, if you like a better answer. With current data this is best answer. With more details I can provide alternative solution (possibly better then accepted answer).