# Why can't I use default template parameters while providing a lambda as an argument?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

I have a templated function that takes an `std::function` argument.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
template<typename T1, typename T2>
void foo(T1& t, std::function<T2()> f)
{
    t = f();
}

int main() {
    std::string s;
    foo<std::string, std::string>(s, (std::function<std::string()>) []() { return "a"; });
    std::cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

Some background: `T2` cannot be inferred while at the same time inferring that the lambda is a function.
`foo(s, []() { return "a"; })` does not work, but
`foo(s, (std::function<std::string()>) []() { return "a"; })` does, and
`foo<std::string, std::string>(s, []() { return "a"; })` does.

Here's the question: suppose I give `T2` a default: `template<typename T1, typename T2 = T1>`. Then
`foo<std::string>(s, []() { return "a"; })` does not work. Why? I provide one template argument, thus I indirectly provide both, so there should be no problem inferring that the lambda is a function.

Comment: lambda is not a `std::function`... Why using `std::function` here?

Comment: `"a"` is not a `std::string` neither BTW.

Comment: Replace `std::function<T2()>` with `T2` or `const T2&` or `T2&&` (depending on edge cases) and it will work just fine. There is no point in having `std::function` in a dependent parameter of a function template. `std::function` is useful if you _don't_ want the parameter to be template-dependent.

Comment: You can block deduction on argument 2 explicitly and make it work: `template<class T>struct foo{using type=T;};template<class T>using foo_t=typename foo<T>::type;` then wrap the std function in `foo_t<>`.

Comment: [I cannot pass lambda as std::function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36030589/i-cannot-pass-lambda-as-stdfunction) and [no implicit conversion in template argument deduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53227713/why-does-the-implicit-type-conversion-not-work-in-template-deduction)

Comment: Closers ALWAYS get it wrong, and NEVER revise their decisions.

Comment: I know lambdas are not functions as I made clear - the point of which was to clarify what the actual question was instead of having people go over stuff I already know, which failed horribly. Nevertheless I got what I needed and more from the answers. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Most importantly you seem to misunderstand what `std::function` is and how they relate to lambdas.

> [...] so there should be no problem inferring that the lambda is a function.

The problem here is that the lambda is not a function. It is also not a `std::function` (and generally not every function is a `std::function`). The lamdba is an instance of an anonymous functor type, ie some type that has an `operator()` overload. `std::function` is a type erased wrapper for all kinds of callables. Lambdas can be converted to a `std::function` provided the signature matches. Though when you do not need type erasure, chances are high that you do not need `std::function`.

---

Next,template argument deduction does not take into account implicit conversions. The lambda is not a `std::function`, it can be converted to one.

> `foo(s, []() { return "a"; })` does not work

Because `[]() { return "a"; }` is not a `std::function<T2()>`, not for any `T2`. The lambda is of some anonymous type.

> `foo(s, (std::function<std::string()>) []() { return "a"; })` does

Here you explicitly cast the lambda to `std::function<std::string()>`. `T2` can be deduced from `std::function<std::string()>`, it matches `std::function<T2()>`.

> `foo<std::string, std::string>(s, []() { return "a"; })` does.

Here, there is no template argument deduction. The lambda can be implicitly converted to `std::function<std::string()>`.

---

> Here's the question: suppose I give T2 a default: `template<typename T1, typename T2 = T1>`. Then
> `foo<std::string>(s, []() { return "a"; })` does not work. Why

This fails to compile for the same reasons as above. The lambda is not a `std::function<std::string()>` and you cannot deduce `std::string` from the lambda because it does not match `std::function<T2()>`.

---

`std::function` is not the type to be used whenever you need to pass a callable around. Your function template should be simply this:

```
template<typename T, typename F>
void foo(T& t, F&& f)
{
    t = f();
}
```

If you want to restrict `F` to callables that return `T` and not something else, you could use concepts.

Though, also in your examples the callable you pass does not always return `T1`. `"a"` is not a `std::string`, it can be converted to one.

Comment: "This fails to compile for the same reasons as above" - why does it not match the case where I provide both template arguments? The default `T2 = T1` should make them equivalent.

Comment: @H.v.M. That's not how deduction is done. Default arguments have no impact on deduction. They are only used if deduction from the function parameter/argument pairs isn't possibly at all (e.g. because the parameter doesn't appear in any parameter). They are not correlated during the deduction process.

Comment: @H.v.M. You can force the deduction to be impossible in that sense by wrapping the function argument in braces, i.e. `foo(s, {[]() { return "a"; }})`. This works because braced function arguments always make the parameter/argument pair a non-deduced context (because braced arguments aren't expressions and don't have types from which deduction would be possible).