# How does the implicit conversion of string to string_view work for operator== in the standard library?

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion, string-view

I'm trying to understand how `operator==` gets considered for overload resolution in the following example in the standard library implementation for Clang or MSVC.

```
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

//#define WORKAROUND 1

namespace tst
{
    template<class T>
    class string_view
    {
#if WORKAROUND
        friend bool operator==( string_view a, string_view b);
#endif
    }; 
    
    template<class T, class A>
    class string
    {
    public:
        operator string_view<T>() const;
    };

#if !WORKAROUND
    template<class T>
    bool operator==( string_view<T> a, string_view<T> b);
#endif
}

void foo()
{
    tst::string<char, int> s1;
    tst::string_view<char> sv;

    if (s1 == sv) {}
    if (sv == s1) {}
}

int main()
{
    std::string s1;
    std::string_view sv;
 
    if (s1 == sv) {}
    if (sv == s1) {}

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles when `WORKAROUND` is defined as it is very well described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9789036/3415353). However, looking into the sources of Clang and MSVC I don't see that this workaround is used by the library. The operator is defined outside of the class simply as:

```
template<class _CharT, class _Traits>
_LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR_SINCE_CXX14 _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
bool operator==(basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits> __lhs,
                basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits> __rhs) _NOEXCEPT
{
    if (__lhs.size() != __rhs.size()) return false;
    return __lhs.compare(__rhs) == 0;
}
```

See [github](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/4085cb380d8f95783842c11e1f41a474b0a11ef3/libcxx/include/string_view#L779).

So my question is how does it work for STL?

Comment: That's what the overloads below the one you copied are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look carefully in the libc++ code there is a workaround present in the code, just after the normal [operator is defined](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/4085cb380d8f95783842c11e1f41a474b0a11ef3/libcxx/include/string_view#L779) there is a [second version](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/4085cb380d8f95783842c11e1f41a474b0a11ef3/libcxx/include/string_view#L789) which is decorated with `__type_identity_t`:

```
template<class _CharT, class _Traits, int = 1>
_LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR_SINCE_CXX14 _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
bool operator==(basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits> __lhs,
                __type_identity_t<basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits> > __rhs) _NOEXCEPT
```

Adding the C++20 equivalent [`std::type_identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity) to your code resolves the problem:

```
    template<class T>
    bool operator==( string_view<T> a, std::type_identity_t<string_view<T>> b);
```

https://godbolt.org/z/86r6c8s1h

As explained in the post you linked to, conversions aren't considered when deducing template types, `std::type_identity` works around this problem.

Cppreference does mention [that this is necessary](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/operator_cmp) but not exactly how it should be implemented:

> The implementation shall provide sufficient additional constexpr and noexcept overloads of these functions so that a `basic_string_view<CharT,Traits>` object `sv` may be compared to another object `t` with an implicit conversion to `basic_string_view<CharT,Traits>`, with semantics identical to comparing `sv` and `basic_string_view<CharT,Traits>(t)`